# Node ldap-client installation error

Tags: node.js, ldap-client

I tried installing the ldap-client node module for nodejs on my local windows machine by running this command, npm install --save ldap-client.

It gives the error as attached

gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\workspace\AJNSDemoProject
gyp ERR! node -v v8.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1

I installed the OpenLDAP client libraries from here (http://www.openldap.org/software/download/) as tgz and extracted that and put the folder in my project root folder.

I am using latest node version 8.10.0

Could you please advice whats wrong in my case?

Thanks

Debug log when run "node-gyp rebuild" command

C:\workspace\AJNSDemoProject>node-gyp rebuild

```
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok  
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2  
gyp info using node@8.10.0 | win32 | x64  
gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\python.exe  
gyp info spawn args [ 'C:\\Users\\niyaza.fazlullah\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',  
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',  
gyp info spawn args   '-f',  
gyp info spawn args   'msvs',  
gyp info spawn args   '-G',  
gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=auto',  
gyp info spawn args   '-I',  
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\workspace\\AJNSDemoProject\\build\\config.gypi',  
gyp info spawn args   '-I',  
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\niyaza.fazlullah\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',  
gyp info spawn args   '-I',  
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\niyaza.fazlullah\\.node-gyp\\8.10.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',  
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',  
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',  
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\niyaza.fazlullah\\.node-gyp\\8.10.0',  
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\niyaza.fazlullah\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',  
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\niyaza.fazlullah\\.node-gyp\\8.10.0\\<(target_arch)\\node.lib',  
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\workspace\\AJNSDemoProject',  
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',  
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',  
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',  
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',  
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\workspace\\AJNSDemoProject\\build',  
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]  
Warning: Missing input files:  
C:\workspace\AJNSDemoProject\build\..\src\binding.cc  
gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe  
gyp info spawn args [ 'build/binding.sln',  
gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',  
gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',  
gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64' ]  
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.  
  binding.cc  
c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '..\src\binding.cc': No such file or directory [C:\workspace\AJNSDem
oProject\build\binding.vcxproj]  
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
gyp ERR! build error  
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1  
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit  (C:\Users\niyaza.fazlullah\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)  
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)  
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)  
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)  
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063  
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"   "C:\\Users\\niyaza.fazlullah\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"  
gyp ERR! cwd C:\workspace\AJNSDemoProject  
gyp ERR! node -v v8.10.0  
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2  
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: run  following command : node-gyp rebuild

Comment: niyaza let me know wheter anything help to you or not?

Comment: Hi Dipak, when I run the above command also it gives the same error.

Comment: but can you post here debug log?

Comment: As I have reviewed npm ldap-client description, it requires to installing open-ldap library in a local machine. Please confirm that you should install open-ldap in your local machine.

Comment: As I have mentioned in my post, I have installed the OpenLDAP client libraries from here (http://www.openldap.org/software/download/) as tgz (which is a winzip folder) and extracted that and put the folder in my project root folder. But I am not sure is this the correct way to do.

Comment: Thanks Dipak. I have updated the log in my post. Please refer.